# Enterprise level Git server

Tags: git

I am new to Git, but I've read and worked most of the Pro Git documentation.  The problem I have having is that I am a Java/Primefaces developer and I was going to set up a server for me and the rest of the Java developers; however, now the infrastructure team wants to join in the fun for their php scripts and the BI team for their SQL scripts.  How do I set up a Git server that allows such a disparate set of interests.

Comment: Git is git, what problem are you facing?

Answer (score 1):

1. Git server can have any amount of (independent) repositories
2. Any team can have any amount of (independent) repositories on any amount of (independent) Git-servers